# Calendar Current Event ID to string SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, calculated-column

The ID of a current event in a calendar is displayed in the format of "ID#.#.yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss"  This format is only displayed as the ID in the current events view. I need to pull this value into another column as a string where I can extract the date, yyyy-mm-dd.  In SPDesigner I've tried setting the current item ID to another field in a WF but all I am getting is the ID# and not the complete current event ID.  Does anyone know how to get the recurrence ID string into another column?  Your help is always appreciated.

Thanks,